# Log console output in a Python Azure Web/Worker Role

Tags: python, visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-worker-roles

I have deployed a simple Python Worker Role on Microsoft Azure, using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, [as per this tutorial](http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Running-Python-worker-role-in-Azure-Step-by-Step.aspx). It works fine locally, but I can't find a way to see the console output after publishing.

I've tried enabling diagnostics, I only get some errors about saying `Global Disk Quota of 2560 MB is less than total minimum quota 2711 MB required by all the tables`.

I've also tried enabling Remote Desktop, but it won't accept my credentials, even though it did accept them when I turned the setting on.

How/Where can I see my application output when deploying a Python Worker Role to Azure?

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried enabling diagnostics, I only get some errors about saying Global Disk Quota of 2560 MB is less than total minimum quota 2711 MB required by all the tables.

For this issue, seems that you may need check these points:

1. When you enabled diagnostics setting, how many Disk Quota you set on your diagnostics? I suggest it is not necessary to set the larger disk if you used the small or extrasamll instance.
   [image]

2.Could you set the Azure Storage account? From these screenshot, you can set the storage account:
[image]

If you have already set the storage account, you could set the another storage account to test it.

> I've also tried enabling Remote Desktop, but it won't accept my credentials, even though it did accept them when I turned the setting on.
>   About enabled the RD on instance, you can follow the reference above as you mentioned. If you wants to set the RD on Azure Portal, Please click into 'Configure' panel, and select Remote, then you can see this picture:

[image]

Then you can click the "connect" button to connect your instance.
Please try it. Any concerns, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

We can install cloud service diagnostics extension for your cloud service, which will log the runtime metrics  in Azure Table Storage. Here is the [official guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics/#how-to-enable-diagnostics-in-a-worker-role) which shows you step by step to enable the diagnostics in a worker role. And according your current situation, you can start with step 4.

And if you need some custom metrics logs, you can also leverage Azure Storage or Databases to host your logs. To integrate Azure Table storage, please refer to [How to use Table storage from Python](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-python-how-to-use-table-storage/)